# Бес- / без-хот-догная кафешка

Tags: орфография, приставка, слитно-дефис, сложные-прилагательные, окказионализмы

Мы знаем, что, если прилагательное образовано от существительного, через дефис пишущегося, используем тоже дефис: *хот-дог — хот-догный*.
Если мы приставку пишем со словом, требующим дефис, то приставка через дефис пишется.
Будет ли сохраняться правило, что с глухими буквами, когда мы определённые приставки используем, мы пишем ***с***, а если звонкая, то ***з***?

***Бес**-хот-догная кафешка.

**Без**-хот-догная кафешка.*

Comment: Лео, вы забыли, что _хо**т**-дог_ пишется через Т. И верно: _хот-догий_. По крайней мере, так написано тут: https://synonyms.su/morphology/h/hot-dog#:~:text=Хот-дог%20—%20прилагательное.%20Неопределенная%20форма,р.%2C%20им.%20п.)%20—%20хот-догий

Comment: Вечер добрый, Максим. А Вы сами-то ознакомились с информацией, на которую даете ссылку? Вот что там имеется: *хот-дог — прилагательное; в предложении имя прилагательное в краткой форме чаще всего выступает в роли сказуемого «хот-дог».* **?!** Я бы не стала доверять **такому** сайту.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр   Если очень надо, то напишите "без-хот-догная". Сравнить: предлог из-под. З – основная форма для приставок на З-, она сохраняется при дефисном написании.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

❶. От Розенталя ([Сложные прилагательные](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49)):

> **6.** Пишутся через дефис:
> **1)** сложные прилагательные, образованные от сложных существительных с дефисным написанием: *анархо-синдикалистский, северо-восточный, юго-юго-западный, норд-остовый, лейб-гвардейский, иваново-вознесенский, нью-йоркский.*
>
> **Примечание.** При наличии приставки такие прилагательные пишутся слитно: *антисоциалдемократический, приамударьинский.*

❷. Бе**сх**ребетный, бе**сх**востый, бе**сх**итростный, бе**сх**арактерный...

❸. Я бы написала окказиональное прилагательное так (с сохранением правила):
хот-дог ↠ *хот-договый* ↠ *бе**сх**отдоговый* ↠ *бе**сх**отдоговая* кафешка.

❹. Примеры:
***Хот-договый** фургон двигаться не мог — настолько качественно я издырявил его* (И. Рясной. Ловушка для олигарха);
*Стояла, нелепая такая, а **хот-договая** булка торчала из клюва, будто крохотная шлюпка* (Р. Бротиган. Уиллард и его кегельбанные призы).

Comment: В «Правилах коррекции», РАНом написанных, однако, сказано, что, есль приставку к слову с дефисом, — нужен снова дефис.

Comment: Чегой-то пропустилось ваше сообщение... Ну да, ну да, есть такая нестыковка. Хорошо, что вы задали дополнительный — анти/социал/демократический — вопрос. Я его, естественно, оценила. Кстати, текстовый редактор ни одно, ни другое слово как ошибку не отмечает.